# How to host a simple index.html with some javascript and css on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to deploy an application through Heroku which is just an index.html page with some javascript and css.
I've connected my Github repository to it as a deployment method, but it never seems to work.

Every time I type "heroku logs", it spits back out:
"npm ERR! missing script: start" first.

From what I've searched, it tells me that I need to add "start": "somefile.js" as a starting point in package.json, but this is a very simple index.html page with javascript invoked from whenever a couple buttons are pressed.

How am I meant to get past this?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku isn't really built for hosting static websites that have no dynamic server backend. If you want to do that, you should look into using a proper static file host like Amazon S3, Netlify, etc.

However -- if you DO want to do this on Heroku, you can do so by creating a really simple application (here's an article which shows you how to do it using Ruby): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @rdegges, you need some sort of http server. A basic node http server is pretty trivial to implement as well.

A full tutorial is available, but the keys steps are:

1. Make sure you have [node, npm, heroku CLI] installed.
2. In the root of your project directory, run `npm init` - (this will create a `package.json` in your root project directory)
3. Run `npm install --save express` - (this will add express as a dependency to the `package.json` file)
4. Create a file named `Procfile` in the root directory.
   (contents: `web: npm app.js`)
5. Create a file named `app.js` in the root directory. (contents below)
6. Commit your changes, push to Heroku - `git push heroku master`

That should do it. Make sure all your files are in a directory called `public` as specified in the `app.js` file or change that to reflect where they actually are.

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Full Tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction